# unity3d - Unable to transfer rotation over UNET

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm using unity 5.5.

Here is my code.

Client.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Player
{
    public string playerName;
    public GameObject avatar;
    public int connectionId;
}


public class Client : MonoBehaviour
{

    private const int MAX_CONNECTION = 100;

    private string ServerIp = "127.0.0.1";

    private int port = 5701;
    private int hostId;

    private int ourClientId;

    private int reliableChannel;
    private int unreliableChannel;

    private int connectionId;

    private float connectionTime;
    private bool isStarted = false;
    private bool isConnected = false;

    private string PlayerName;


    public GameObject characterPrefab;
    public Dictionary<int,Player> Players = new Dictionary<int, Player>();

    private byte error;

    public void Connect()
    {
        // Does the player have a name ?

        string pName = GameObject.Find("NameInput").GetComponent<InputField>().text;

        if(PlayerName == "")
        {
            Debug.Log("You must write you name!");
            return;
        }

        PlayerName = pName;

        NetworkTransport.Init();

        ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

        reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);

        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTION);

        hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, 0);
        connectionId = NetworkTransport.Connect(hostId,ServerIp,port,0, out error);

        connectionTime = Time.time;
        isConnected = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isConnected)
        {
            return;
        }

        int recHostId;
        int connectionId;
        int channelId;
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int dataSize;
        byte error;
        NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);
        switch (recData)
        {

            case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:       //3
                string msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(recBuffer, 0, dataSize);
                Debug.Log("Receiving: " + msg);

                string[] splitData = msg.Split('|');

                switch (splitData[0])
                {
                    case "ASKPLAYERNAME":
                        OnAskName(splitData);
                    break;

                    case "CNN":
                        SpawnPlayer(splitData[1],int.Parse(splitData[2]));
                        break;
                    case "DC":
                        CharacterDisconnected(int.Parse(splitData[1]));
                        break;
                    case "ASKCHARACTERPOSITION":
                        OnAskPosition(splitData);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Debug.Log("Invalid Client meesage : " + msg);
                        break;

                }

                break;

        }
    }

    private void OnAskName(string[] data)
    {
        ourClientId = int.Parse(data[1]);

        //Send our name to the server.

        Send("PLAYERNAME|" + PlayerName, reliableChannel);

        //Create all the other players.

        for(int i = 2; i < data.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            string[] d = data[i].Split('%');

                SpawnPlayer(d[0], int.Parse(d[1]));

        }
    }

    private void OnAskPosition(string[] data)
    {
        if (!isStarted)
            return;
        //Update everyone else position;
        for (int i = 1; i <= data.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            string[] d = data[i].Split('%');
            //Prevent the server from updating us.
            if (ourClientId != int.Parse(d[0]))
            {
                Vector3 position = Vector3.zero;
                Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(float.Parse(d[4]), float.Parse(d[5]), float.Parse(d[6]));
                position.x = float.Parse(d[1]);
                position.y = float.Parse(d[2]);
                position.z = float.Parse(d[3]);
                Players[int.Parse(d[0])].avatar.transform.position = position;
                //Debug.Log("My position" + transform.position + "- Going to:" + position);
                Players[int.Parse(d[0])].avatar.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * 10);
            }


        }
        //Send our own position;
        Vector3 myPosition = Players[ourClientId].avatar.transform.position; //Taking my position.
        Quaternion myRotation = Players[ourClientId].avatar.transform.rotation; //Taking my rotaion.
        Debug.Log("Character rotation:" + myRotation);
        string m = "CHARACTERPOSITION|" + myPosition.x.ToString() + '|' + myPosition.y.ToString() + '|' + myPosition.z.ToString() + '|' + myRotation.x.ToString() + '|' + myRotation.y.ToString() + '|' + myRotation.z.ToString();
        Send(m, unreliableChannel);


    }

    private void SpawnPlayer(string playerName, int cnnid)
    {
        GameObject go = Instantiate(characterPrefab) as GameObject;

        // Is this ours?
        if(cnnid == ourClientId)
        {
            // Add mobility.
            go.AddComponent<CharacterMovement>();
            go.AddComponent<Character>();
            // REmove canvas.
            GameObject.Find("Canvas").SetActive(false);
            isStarted = true;
        }

        Player p = new Player();
        p.avatar = go;
        p.playerName = playerName;
        p.connectionId = cnnid;
        p.avatar.GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>().text = playerName;
        Players.Add(cnnid,p);

    }

    private void CharacterDisconnected(int cnnid)
    {
        Destroy(Players[cnnid].avatar);
        Players.Remove(cnnid);
    }

    private void Send(string message, int channelId)
    {
        Debug.Log("Sending : " + message);
        byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
             NetworkTransport.Send(hostId, connectionId, channelId, msg, message.Length * sizeof(char), out error);

    }
}
```

Here is my Server.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class ServerClient
{
    public int connectionId;
    public string playerName;
    public Vector3 playerPosition;
    public Quaternion playerRotation;
}

public class Server : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const int MAX_CONNECTION = 100;

    private int port = 5701;
    private int hostId;

    private int reliableChannel;
    private int unreliableChannel;

    private bool isStarted = false;
    private byte error;

    private List<ServerClient> clients = new List<ServerClient>();

    private float lastMovementUpdate;
    private float movementUpdateRate = 0.05f;

    private void Start()
    {
        NetworkTransport.Init();

        ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

        reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);

        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTION);

        hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port, null);

        isStarted = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isStarted)
        {
            return;
        }

        int recHostId;
        int connectionId;
        int channelId;
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int dataSize;
        byte error;
        NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);
        switch (recData)
        {
            case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:    //2
                Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + " has connected.");
                OnConnection(connectionId);
                break;
            case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:       //3
                string msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(recBuffer, 0, dataSize);
                Debug.Log("Receiving from " + connectionId + " has sent : " + msg);
                string[] splitData = msg.Split('|');

                switch (splitData[0])
                {
                    case "PLAYERNAME":
                        OnPlayerName(connectionId, splitData[1]);
                        break;
                    case "CHARACTERPOSITION":
                        OnCharacterPosition(connectionId, float.Parse(splitData[1]), float.Parse(splitData[2]), float.Parse(splitData[3]), float.Parse(splitData[4]), float.Parse(splitData[5]), float.Parse(splitData[6]));
                        break;
                    default:
                        Debug.Log("Invalid Server meesage : " + msg);
                        break;

                }

                break;

                break;
            case NetworkEventType.DisconnectEvent: //4
                Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + " has disconnected.");
                OnDisconnection(connectionId);
                break;
        }

        //Ask player for position.
        if(Time.time - lastMovementUpdate > movementUpdateRate)
        {
            lastMovementUpdate = Time.time;
            string m = "ASKCHARACTERPOSITION|";

            foreach (ServerClient sc in clients)
            {
                m += sc.connectionId.ToString() + '%' + sc.playerPosition.x.ToString() + '%' + sc.playerPosition.y.ToString() + '%' + sc.playerPosition.z.ToString() + '%' + sc.playerRotation.x.ToString() + '%' + sc.playerRotation.y.ToString() + '%' + sc.playerRotation.z.ToString() + '|';
            }
            m = m.Trim('|');
            Send(m, unreliableChannel, clients);
        }
    }
    private void OnConnection(int cnnId)
    {
        // Add him to online list
        ServerClient c = new ServerClient();
        c.connectionId = cnnId;
        c.playerName = "TEMP";
        clients.Add(c);


        // Assing player id

        // Request player name and send to all players

        string msg = "ASKPLAYERNAME|" + cnnId + "|";
        foreach (ServerClient sc in clients)
        {
            msg += sc.playerName + '%' + sc.connectionId + '|';
        }
            msg = msg.Trim('|');
            Send(msg, reliableChannel, cnnId);


    }
    private void OnDisconnection(int cnnId)
    {
        // Remove player from our client list
        clients.Remove(clients.Find(x => x.connectionId == cnnId));
        //Tell everyone somebody dissconnected
        Send("DC|" + cnnId, reliableChannel, clients);
    }
    private void OnPlayerName(int cnnId, string playerName)
    {
        // Ling the name to the connection id.
        clients.Find(x => x.connectionId == cnnId).playerName = playerName;
        // Tell everybody new player has connected.
        Send("CNN|" + playerName + '|' + cnnId, reliableChannel, clients);
    }
    private void OnCharacterPosition(int cnnId, float x, float y, float z, float rx, float ry, float rz)
    {
        Quaternion characterRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rx,ry,rz);
        Debug.Log("Character rotation: " + characterRotation);
        clients.Find(c => c.connectionId == cnnId).playerPosition = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        //clients.Find(c => c.connectionId == cnnId).playerRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 30, 0));
    }
    private void Send(string message, int channelId, int cnnId)
        {
            List<ServerClient> c = new List<ServerClient>();
            c.Add(clients.Find(x => x.connectionId == cnnId));
            Send(message, channelId, c);
        }
    private void Send(string message, int channelId, List<ServerClient> c)
        {
            Debug.Log("Sending : " + message);
            byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
            foreach(ServerClient sc in c)
            {
                NetworkTransport.Send(hostId, sc.connectionId, channelId, msg, message.Length * sizeof(char), out error);
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is my CharacterMovement.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController controller;
    private float verticalVelocity;

    private void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();


    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //inputs = location variable
        Vector3 location = Vector3.zero;

        location.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            verticalVelocity = -1;
            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            {
                verticalVelocity = 10;
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * CharacterGlobals.CharacterMovementSpeed;
                Debug.Log("Location: " + transform.position);
                //Debug.Log("Character speed is: " + CharacterGlobals.CharacterMovementSpeed);
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
                transform.position -= transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * CharacterGlobals.CharacterMovementSpeed;
                // Decrease character speed by - CharacterGlobals.CharacterMovementSpeed -= 1;
                Debug.Log("Location: " + transform.position);
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                transform.Rotate(0, -3, 0);
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                transform.Rotate(0, 3, 0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            verticalVelocity -= 14.0f * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        location.y = verticalVelocity;

        controller.Move(location * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I have created a successfully multyplayer connection. When character login it is spawned and when it moves the position is synced well. So i am able to update character position but i'm not able to update character rotation.
I binded rotation of the character on pressing buttons `A` and `D`. There is no problem on the character 1 to rotate but you can not see that rotation on character 2.

I hope i have explained my problem well enough. Where i my mistake?
Why the character position does not update?

Answer (score 1):

At a glance it looks like you're not actually setting the Quaternion server-side.

```
private void OnCharacterPosition(int cnnId, float x, float y, float z, float rx, float ry, float rz)
{
    Quaternion characterRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rx,ry,rz);
    Debug.Log("Character rotation: " + characterRotation);
    clients.Find(c => c.connectionId == cnnId).playerPosition = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    //clients.Find(c => c.connectionId == cnnId).playerRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 30, 0));
}
```

Try uncommenting your line at the bottom and replacing it with the characterRotation Quaternion you created.

```
private void OnCharacterPosition(int cnnId, float x, float y, float z, float rx, float ry, float rz)
    {
        Quaternion characterRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rx,ry,rz);
        clients.Find(c => c.connectionId == cnnId).playerPosition = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        clients.Find(c => c.connectionId == cnnId).playerRotation = characterRotation;
    }
```

This may fix this one problem, but I highly recommend you try to gain a better understanding of Unity before you dive into Networking. From the code you've written there is a lot of evidence that you are very new to Unity (for instance, rotating in Update() without multiplying your value by something like Time.deltaTime will mean your character movement is frame-rate dependent, a classic rookie mistake).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and advice but still the problem is the same. The rotation is not updating.